# How to perform log rotation with Gunicorn?

Tags: logging, gunicorn, logrotate

I searched through the net but didn't get the concrete answer or example of `"how to use log rotation with Gunicorn?"`.
It would be great if someone provide an example.

Answer (score 27):

If you do not want to bother with logrotare you can use a full python/gunicorn solution using python logging facilities.

Create a file named `log.conf` with the content below. This will rotate the error log file and access log file daily and will keep the logs for 90 days. Log level is set to INFO.

Than, start gunicorn adding a command line parameter `--log-config log.conf`. Remove the `--access-logfile`,  `--error-logfile` and `--log-level` parameters, as the log.conf will take care of everything.

More info on how to configure the logger is available in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html).

Here below is the content of `log.conf`. For another example look at [gunicorn source code](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/logging.conf).

HTH

```
[loggers]
keys=root, gunicorn.error, gunicorn.access

[handlers]
keys=console, error_file, access_file

[formatters]
keys=generic, access

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console

[logger_gunicorn.error]
level=INFO
handlers=error_file
propagate=1
qualname=gunicorn.error

[logger_gunicorn.access]
level=INFO
handlers=access_file
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.access

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_error_file]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=generic
args=('/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn-error.log', 'midnight', 1, 90, 'utf-8')

[handler_access_file]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=access
args=('/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn-access.log', 'midnight', 1, 90, 'utf-8')

[formatter_generic]
format=%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
class=logging.Formatter

[formatter_access]
format=%(message)s
class=logging.Formatter
```

Answer (score 19):

Gunicorn's documentation says you can setup log rotation with `logrotate` (a linux command):

> Logs can be automatically rotated and compressed using logrotate.

Doc link: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/install.html?highlight=logrotate#debian-gnu-linux

So I guess Gunicorn provides itself no way to rotate log.

Here is an example of my configuration file, placed in `/etc/logrotate.d/my_app`:

```
/path/to/my/logs/gunicorn-access.log /path/to/my/logs/gunicorn-error.log {
    monthly
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m
    dateyesterday
    rotate 10000
}
```

Rotate monthly, add -YEAR-MONTH to rotated files, keep 10000 rotated files (see `man logrotate`).

The paths at first line are declared in my `gunicorn_start` script, something like:

```
/my/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn OPTIONS \
    --access-logfile /path/to/my/logs/gunicorn-access.log \
    --error-logfile /path/to/my/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

Comment: Where do we specify gunicorn to use the settings from `my_app`?

Comment: You don't. The log rotation is done by logrotate, not gunicorn.

Answer (score 14):

doc link : https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#logging

```
Logging
Logging can be configured by using various flags detailed in the configuration documentation or by creating a logging configuration file. Send the USR1 signal to rotate logs if you are using the logrotate utility:
kill -USR1 $(cat /var/run/gunicorn.pid)
```

so you can write the configuration file like this:

```
/yourpath/log/gunicorn.* {
daily
rotate 30
compress
dateext
dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
notifempty
sharedscripts
postrotate
    kill -USR1 $(cat /yourpath/run/gunicorn.pid)
endscript
}
```

rotate everyday

Comment: This worked. I am running gunicorn via supervisor, so I had to put a supervisordctl restart <program name> in the postrotate script. Feels like a hack, but works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a change to Charlie's approach, `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler` doesn't work in recent python(3.8), so create a file,

*simple_logger.py*

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
```

and update class line in *log.conf*,

```
class=simple_logger.TimedRotatingFileHandler
```

It worked!

**NOTE: Rotation works but data pushed to logs is not in sequential.**