# How to specify gunicorn log max size

Tags: gunicorn

I'm running gunicorn as:

```
guiconrn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --log-file gunicorn.log myapp:app
```

Seems like `gunicorn.log` keeps growing. Is there a way to specify a max size of the log file, so that if it reaches max size, it'll just override it.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see gunicorn setting related to max log size. You could use `logrotate`. https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/

Comment: Question is from 2018, wow :-) I don't know any program on unix that do manage their own log file size. Buffers yes, but not log size. Always `logrotate`.

Comment: I am not sure it is good practice, as log rotate seems to be such a commonly used tool. But I believe my python solution will work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424335/how-to-perform-log-rotation-with-gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

I believe there might be a "python only" solution using the [rotating file handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) provided in the internal lib of python. (at least 3.10)

## To test

I created a pet project for you to fiddle with:

1. Create the following python file

`test_logs.py`

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import time

logging.config.fileConfig(fname='log.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)


while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    logging.debug('This is a debug message')
    logging.info('This is an info message')
    logging.warning('This is a warning message')
    logging.error('This is an error message')
    logging.critical('This is a critical message')
```

2. Create the following config file

`log.conf`

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=rotatingHandler

[formatters]
keys=sampleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=rotatingHandler

[handler_rotatingHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=sampleFormatter
args=('./logs/logs.log', 'a', 1200, 1, 'utf-8')

[formatter_sampleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

3. Create the `./logs` directory
4. Run `python test_logs.py`

## To Understand

As you may have noticed already, the setting that allow for this behaviour is `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` and the provided arguments `args=('./logs/logs.log', 'a', 1200, 10, 'utf-8')`

`RotatingFileHandler` is a [stream handler writing to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler). That allow for 2 parameters of interest:

- `maxBytes` set arbitrarily at 1200
- `backupCount` set arbitrarily to 10

The behaviour is that upon reaching `1200 Bytes` in size, the file is closed, renamed to `/logs/logs.log.<a number up to 10>` and a new file is opened.

**BUT** is any of `maxBytes` or `backupCount` is 0. No rotation is done !

## In Gunicorn

As per the [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logconfig) you can feed a config file.

This could look like:

```
guiconrn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --log-config log.conf myapp:app
```

You will need to tweak it to your existing setup.

Comment: Acturally, I have been using  `RotatingFileHandler` since Python>3.3 , 
I just put my draft code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu/Linux,  suggest to use `logrotate` to manage your logs, do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643449/6705684

Since Python>3.3, With `RotatingFileHandler`, here is my solution(MacOS/Windows/Linux/...) :

```py
import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
fmt_str = '[%(asctime)s]%(module)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s'
fmt = logging.Formatter(fmt_str)

def rotating_logger(name, fmt=fmt,
                      level=logging.INFO,
                      logfile='.log',
                      maxBytes=10 * 1024 * 1024,
                      backupCount=5,
                      **kwargs
                      ):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    hdl = RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=maxBytes, backupCount=backupCount)
    hdl.setLevel(level)
    hdl.setFormatter(fmt)

    logger.addHandler(hdl)
    return logger
```

more refer:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler