# How to rotate Gunicorn access & error logs using a dict config in python (or other ways)?

Tags: python, logging, configuration, gunicorn, logrotate

I'm running Gunicorn and all the access and error logs are appended to 2 files (one for access and one for error).  I'm looking for ways to rotate out those logs on a daily basis as to not have 2 massive files for all logs. I was thinking of passing in a dict config into the Gunicorn configuration file, however it doesn't seem to be working. Also, I'm aware a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424335/how-to-perform-log-rotation-with-gunicorn#:%7E:text=Logs%20can%20be%20automatically%20rotated%20and%20compressed%20using%20logrotate.&text=So%20I%20guess%20Gunicorn%20provides%20itself%20no%20way%20to%20rotate%20log.&text=Rotate%20monthly%2C%20add%20%2DYEAR%2D,files%20(see%20man%20logrotate%20).), but that is rotating logs using the **logrotate** linux command which I cannot use in my current situation. Is there anyone who has run into something similar and found a workaround?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65613641/1116171) does exactly what you need. Cheers